# what is the structure for S3 endpoint when wiring into HIVE?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am attempting to connect HIVE to an S3 bucket containing some parquet files.. via this tutorial

https://janakiev.com/blog/presto-trino-s3/

I've gotten to the point where i am ready to inject my AWS credentials.. and the S3 URI.. but it seems there is no URI but.. an "endpoint" .  I went ahead and created a endpoint but.. how am I supposed to input it?  I am seeing multiple documentations but with conflicting inputs because they all focus on local "s3 compatible" storage

```
<property>
    <name>fs.s3a.endpoint</name>
    <value>S3_ENDPOINT</value>
</property>
```

Is this correct?

```
S3_ENDPOINT=https://s3.MY_REGION.amazonaws.com/SOME_BUCKET_NAME_123-s3alias
```

or do I simply use the URI?

```
s3://arn:aws:s3:REGION_NAME:1234567:accesspoint/mybucket-name
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OKay I found the page explaining what an S3 endpoint is..

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/s3.html#s3_website_region_endpoints

and they explain the setup on this page

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteEndpoints.html

```
Depending on your Region, your Amazon S3 website endpoint follows one of these two formats.

    s3-website dash (-) Region ‐ http://bucket-name.s3-website-Region.amazonaws.com

    s3-website dot (.) Region ‐ http://bucket-name.s3-website.Region.amazonaws.com
```